# Split Table by Two Columns

Tags: r, split

I hope this is not a dupe - I have searched long and hard and have found many similar questions but nothing that addresses my issue.

I have a dataframe, 1 column containing data and the other 2 columns are quantile measures I have calculated earlier.

```
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(data = 100:199, quantile1 = runif(100), quantile2 = runif(100))
head(d)

  data quantile1 quantile2
1  100 0.2875775 0.5999890
2  101 0.7883051 0.3328235
3  102 0.4089769 0.4886130
4  103 0.8830174 0.9544738
5  104 0.9404673 0.4829024
6  105 0.0455565 0.8903502
```

I would like a smart way split the data according to quantile1 and quantile2 columns. e.g. I want the rows where quantile1 is < 0.25 and quantile2 is > 0.5.  I am currently doing this with:

```
d[d[,2] < 0.25 & d[,3] > 0.5, ]
```

This works but is a bit of a hassle if I have many subsets I want to split my data into.  I am looking at splitting at the following boundaries:

```
quantile1 0.25, 0.75 (three subsets)
```

and then for each subset of quantile1, further split the boundary:

```
quantile2 0.5 (2 subsets)
```

so yielding 6 subsets in total.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `split` and `findInterval` together, perhaps something like:

```
dsplit <- split(d, list(findInterval(d[, "quantile1"], vec=c(0, .25, .75)),
                        findInterval(d[, "quantile2"], vec=c(0, .5))))
```

This creates a `list` of 6 `data.frame`s. The first three `data.frame`s are those where "quantile2" is less than .5, and the second three are those where it is greater than 5.

```
str(dsplit)
# List of 6
#  $ 1.1:'data.frame':    9 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ data     : int [1:9] 139 140 145 146 153 155 161 190 195
#   ..$ quantile1: num [1:9] 0.232 0.143 0.139 0.233 0.122 ...
#   ..$ quantile2: num [1:9] 0.439 0.312 0.231 0.239 0.246 ...
#  $ 2.1:'data.frame':  27 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ data     : int [1:27] 102 108 109 111 112 121 122 124 126 127 ...
#   ..$ quantile1: num [1:27] 0.409 0.551 0.457 0.453 0.678 ...
#   ..$ quantile2: num [1:27] 0.4886 0.4107 0.1471 0.3012 0.0607 ...
#  $ 3.1:'data.frame':  14 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ data     : int [1:14] 101 104 115 119 123 152 157 158 164 167 ...
#   ..$ quantile1: num [1:14] 0.788 0.94 0.9 0.955 0.994 ...
#   ..$ quantile2: num [1:14] 0.333 0.483 0.142 0.405 0.22 ...
#  $ 1.2:'data.frame':  17 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ data     : int [1:17] 105 114 116 117 129 134 137 144 150 156 ...
#   ..$ quantile1: num [1:17] 0.0456 0.1029 0.2461 0.0421 0.1471 ...
#   ..$ quantile2: num [1:17] 0.89 0.721 0.549 0.954 0.69 ...
#  $ 2.2:'data.frame':  20 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ data     : int [1:20] 100 106 113 118 125 132 135 138 160 162 ...
#   ..$ quantile1: num [1:20] 0.288 0.528 0.573 0.328 0.709 ...
#   ..$ quantile2: num [1:20] 0.6 0.914 0.948 0.585 0.984 ...
#  $ 3.2:'data.frame':  13 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ data     : int [1:13] 103 107 110 120 130 131 133 136 149 166 ...
#   ..$ quantile1: num [1:13] 0.883 0.892 0.957 0.89 0.963 ...
#   ..$ quantile2: num [1:13] 0.954 0.609 0.935 0.648 0.619 ...
```

You can verify the desired output according to your example in your question.

```
dsplit[[4]]
#    data    quantile1 quantile2
# 6   105 0.0455564994 0.8903502
# 15  114 0.1029246827 0.7205963
# 17  116 0.2460877344 0.5492847
# 18  117 0.0420595335 0.9540912
# 30  129 0.1471136473 0.6900071
# 35  134 0.0246136845 0.5211357
# 38  137 0.2164079358 0.7862816
# 45  144 0.1524447477 0.8427293
# 51  150 0.0458311667 0.8474532
# 57  156 0.1275316502 0.5719353
# 74  173 0.0006247733 0.7465680
# 76  175 0.2201188852 0.6180179
# 80  179 0.1111354243 0.5817501
# 81  180 0.2436194727 0.8397678
# 85  184 0.1028646443 0.5943432
# 90  189 0.1750526503 0.9018744
# 98  197 0.0935949867 0.6592303

yourexample <- d[d[, 2] < 0.25 & d[,3] > 0.5, ]
identical(dsplit[[4]], yourexample)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: congrats on your 10k mrdwab! also noticing the name change!

Comment: @flodel, thanks. I hit the 10k yesterday sometime... and I can now see dead posts... {insert maniacal laugh}.

Comment: This does exactly what I need.  As a further refinement, can I change the order the lists are returned? I want the two data frames returned to be the quantile1's first interval and the two intervals for quantile2.  Then the second two data frames to be quantile2's second interval and the two intervals for quantile2.  Thanks!

Comment: @mchangun, Maybe just try changing the order of the two things I have in `list` above. (In other words, ask R to split by "quantile2" first, then by "quantile1").

Answer (score 2):

Someone may come up with a more elegant solution, but this is what I've done in similar situations:

```
> split(d, list(cut(d[,2], c(0,.25,.75,1)), cut(d[,3], c(0,.5,1)))) -> NewD
> NewD                 # Shows the six tables    


> lapply(NewD, nrow)   # Shows the name/size of each resulting data frame
$`(0,0.25].(0,0.5]`
[1] 9

$`(0.25,0.75].(0,0.5]`
[1] 27

$`(0.75,1].(0,0.5]`
[1] 14

$`(0,0.25].(0.5,1]`
[1] 17

$`(0.25,0.75].(0.5,1]`
[1] 20

$`(0.75,1].(0.5,1]`
[1] 13
```

The `split` function creates new data frames within a `list` based on the criteria in the second argument (which in this case is a list). The `cut` function divides a vector into user specified intervals (or number of equally spaced intervals if you want).

You can rename these data frames with something like `names(NewD) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use **plyr** for splitting, because it's very eco-friendly and prepare data for future plot with ggplot2.

1) bin quatile1,quantile2 groups of similar size using cut

```
     dat$qt1 <- cut(dat$quantile1,c(0,0.25,0.75,1),include.lowest=TRUE)
     dat$qt2 <- cut(dat$quantile2,c(0,0.5,1),include.lowest=TRUE)
```

2) I use melt to reshape data using my discrete identifiers(qt1,qt2)

```
     library(reshape2)
     mm <- melt(dat,measure.vars='data')
```

Now I can play with my melted data , e.g:

```
acast(mm,qt1~qt2)
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
            [0,0.5] (0.5,1]
[0,0.25]          9      18
(0.25,0.75]      26      22
(0.75,1]         18       7
```

or I can plot the data using ggplot:

```
 library(ggplot2) 
 ggplot(data=mm)+geom_bar(aes(x=qt1,fill=qt2,group=qt2),position='dodge')
```

[image]